# Laravel - php artisan migrate, table already exists

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I am trying to run a new migration between two of my tables however when I run `php artisan migrate` it's showing:

> *SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'packings' already exists (SQL: create table `packings` (`id` bigint
>   unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `trip_id` int not null,
>   `title` varchar(191) not null, `is_complete` tinyint(1) not null,
>   `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default
>   character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')*

Packings is a table I made last week...
I tried to run `php artisan migrate:rollback` and it shows..

> *Cannot declare class `AddTripsIdToEvents`, because the name is already
>   in use*

This class is from another migration I had made weeks ago.

I don't know how to fix this without wrecking my website and losing data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think did migrate but fail/error on foreign key or something like that, so table created but migration fails and not saved on migrations table. You just need to delete table `packings` manually in the SQL command or DB management like PHPMyAdmin.

> Cannot declare class AddTripsIdToEvents, because the name is already in use

above error is shown because you have same migration class name. just change one to another name and don't forget to change the file name too.